# How to wipe a user's post history on XenForo forum?

Tags: xenforo

XenForo doesn't offer a way to mass-delete user's threads and messages, each message has to be removed individually.

As an administrator, how can I wipe a user's post history?

Answer (score 2):

As admin, you should have access to the database. Using a single SQL query, you can remove anything. Lookup the UserID for the specific user, and the name of the column used, then figure out in which table the posts are stored, and perform a query similar to the following:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `UserID`="1"
```

Replace `table` with the correct tablename
Replace `UserID` with the correct column name
Replace "1" with the correct user id.

**Keep in mind that if you don't do this correctly, you can remove far more than just the required posts, so backup your database first!**

You can also look for [support from the developers](https://xenforo.com/customers/support). They should be able to tell you the exact SQL query.

If you haven't worked with databases before, you may want to consider deleting the posts manually.